# If there are any default aws class have to all event mapping?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, sdk

I want the AWS event mapping class that class supported all the AWS services.

I created the custom event objects (only for handler) separately.

I need those events in one class. So, if there are any AWS class have to support the Event mapping class.

Comment: What's the point when they all have their own unique structures/fields?

Comment: I am asking if there are any common patterns have or not and that pattern support to all AWS services also.